# How to change the style of a geojson feature on a click event in react leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I am working on a react app with react leaflet. When you click on a country on the leaflet map, the country is supposed to change style (turn a different colour). I can't get this to work. In the current implementation the mouseover, and mouseout events work, but not click. At the moment, the click changes the style for a split second during the click event, then returns to the default style. I need the color change to be persist beyond the click event

If anyone has any idea how to fix this, I would be very grateful:

**App.jsx**

```js
function App() {
  const {
    fetchCountryData,
    fetchPeopleIndicatorData,
    fetchEconomicIndicatorData,
    fetchEnvironmentIndicatorData,
  } = useCountryData();

  const [clickedCountry, setClickedCountry] = useState(null);
  const [countryData, setCountryData] = useState([]);
  const [peopleIndicatorData, setPeopleIndicatorData] = useState([]);
  const [environmentIndicatorData, setEnvironmentIndicatorData] = useState([]);
  const [economicIndicatorData, setEconomicIndicatorData] = useState([]);
  const [sidebarIsOpen, setSidebarIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleCountryClick = async (country) => {
    if (clickedCountry === country) {
      setClickedCountry(null);
      setSidebarIsOpen(false);
    } else {
      setClickedCountry(country);
      const countryData = await fetchCountryData(country.properties.ISO_A3);
      setCountryData(countryData);
      setPeopleIndicatorData(
        await fetchPeopleIndicatorData(country.properties.ISO_A3)
      );
      setEconomicIndicatorData(
        await fetchEconomicIndicatorData(country.properties.ISO_A3)
      );
      setEnvironmentIndicatorData(
        await fetchEnvironmentIndicatorData(country.properties.ISO_A3)
      );
      setSidebarIsOpen(true);
    }
  };

  const defaultStyle = {
    fillColor: "#000",
    fillOpacity: 0.7,
    weight: 3,
    opacity: 0.7,
    dashArray: 3,
    color: "black",
  };

  const highlightStyle = {
    fillOpacity: 0.7,
    weight: 5,
    dashArray: "",
    color: "#807c7c",
    fillColor: "#ffffff",
  };

  const clickStyle = {
    fillColor: "#fa0000",
    fillOpacity: 1,
    weight: 5,
    opacity: 1,
    dashArray: "",
    color: "#807c7c",
  };

  const onEachCountry = (country, layer) => {
    layer.on({
      click: (e) => {
        e.target.setStyle(clickStyle);
        handleCountryClick(country);
      },
      mouseover: (e) => {
        if (clickedCountry !== country) {
          e.target.setStyle(highlightStyle);
        }
      },
      mouseout: (e) => {
        if (clickedCountry !== country) {
          e.target.setStyle(defaultStyle);
        }
      },
    });
  };

  const handleSidebarClose = () => {
    setClickedCountry(null);
    setSidebarIsOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="map-container">
        <MapContainer>
          <TileLayer
            url="https://api.maptiler.com/maps/basic-v2/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?"
          />
          <GeoJSON
            data={countriesData.features}
            style={defaultStyle}
            onEachFeature={onEachCountry}
          />
        </MapContainer>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your on-click code is calling `e.target.setStyle(....)` which sets the style of the element being targeted, and then calls `handleCountryClick()` which sets different state variable values.

The setting of different state variable values will cause the component to re-render, which I suspect is losing the value applied to the `e.target.setStyle(.....)`.

I think you need to set the "selected style" to a state variable, and then use that state variable in your code:

```js
const [theGeoStyle, setTheGeoStyle] = useState(defaultStyle);

// ....

<GeoJSON
  data={countriesData.features}
  style={theGeoStyle}
  onEachFeature={onEachCountry}
/>
```

and change your on-click handler to use `setTheGeoStyle(clickStyle)`